# Whats is the difference between the following object declarations?

Tags: javascript, object

I am working on a PoC , i stumbled across some code but i don't get the difference or know this way of declaring objects, difference between d and g

```
var d;
(function(d) {
  function f() {
    console.log(23);
  }
  d.fo = f;
})
(d || (d = {}));

var g = {
  fo: function() {
    console.log(44);
  },

  me: function() {
    console.log(33);
  }
}
d.fo();
g.fo()
```

Comment: The second way is cleaner I guess. The first way uses IIFE but I don't think there is any need for IIFE

Comment: Take a look at Object Literal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The first method allows you to add the `fo` method to any existing object in `d`, it creates a new object by default if `d` is not initialized. E.g. you can change

```
var d;
```

to

```
var d = { a: 3};
```

The second method always creates a new object `g` that only has the properties that are defined in it (although you could always add new properties later).

Other than these, there's little significant difference, they're just different styles.